# Jmeter Hbase testing , How to preform the load testing for Big data?

Tags: jmeter, bigdata, performance-testing, load-testing, query-performance

I am new to jmeter Hbase load testing, i have install all plugins related to Hbase load testing, can any one help what exactly i need to do load testing on Hbase and what all need to capture the details related to Hbase load testing.

1. what are the scenarios i need to execute and how i can proceed the Hbase load testing.

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter doesn't support HBase testing out of the box, first of all you will need to install **Hadoop/HBase Testing** plugins, you can do this using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

   [image]
2. `what are the scenarios i need to execute` - we don't know, you mention [load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing#Software_load_testing) and it means that you should put your HBase instance under **anticipated** load, in other words your test must represent real life HBase usage. You should ask your team for the details. If no one knows or unwilling to share the information you can execute the real life scenario using your system user interface or API or whatever and check HBase logs to get the relevant queries from there.
3. `how i can proceed the Hbase load testing` - given you have the plugin and the queries you can use the relevant HBase test elements, most probably HBase Connection Config is a must and HBase CRUD Sampler will cover 99% of your needs. You might also be interested in [How to Load Test HBase with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-hbase-with-jmeter) article